# How to remove "Submit Query" during printing prime faces component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-11

I must print some component from html page. I used  from Prime Faces, but I have some problem.

Internet Explorer 11 add some text to printed images ("Submit Query").

Problem occur in h:commandButton which have empty value.

How I may resolve this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve by using css `background-image` with image in order to present a background image.

```
<h:commandButton value=" " style="background-image: url(your-image.png)" />
```

If you do not want to have the appearance of a button, you can nest `<h:graphicImage>` inside
`<h:commandLink>` and  instead.

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <h:graphicImage value="your-image.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```